# What is the AS3 loop code for this code?

Tags: actionscript-3

its a part of my code:

```
private var page_1:Page_1 = new Page_1();
private var page_2:Page_2 = new Page_2();
.
.
.
private var page_99:Page_99 = new Page_99();
private var page_100:Page_100 = new Page_100();
```

Is it possible do that with a loop?
p.s:sorry for my bad english:(

Comment: Maybe. Can we see what Page_1 class and Page_2 class look like?

Comment: @mitim they are movieclips

Comment: @mitim It is, one has to use `getDefinitionByName()` to get class def for `"Page_"+i`, and I'd better add these pages to an array instead of making 100 separate vars.

Comment: @Vesper Yes, I had that in my mind too, but was wondering if they were classes that could have been refractored in to one class and passed their unique values in to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So can't create a private members but if you can replace it with an array or vector you can do this:

```
private var m_pages: Array = [];


    for ( var i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )
    {
        var symbolClass:Class =getDefinitionByName("Page_" + i) as Class;
        var page = new symbolClass();
        m_pages.push( page );
    }
```